# life cycle of compiled assembly in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compilation, .net-assembly

I compiled code by `CompileAssemblyFromSource` and hold the results of the compilation in **memory** like [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation.aspx). I used it for invoke method by `reflection` in web application(ASP.Net).

In `page load` I check whether it exists in memory. If it did't exist, I must compile code to an in-memory assembly again.

In this scenario, When I refreshed my page and get assembly by `Type.GetType`, this is always `null`.

**Question:** What is life cycle of compiled assembly in memory (In web form)?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if the real issue here is you using `Type.GetType` on something that it is never going to resolve, no matter how many times you load it. Store the `Assembly` instance somewhere, instead. AFAIK, it isn't going to unload the assembly, ever (except `AppDomain` death)

Comment: The *assembly* tag you used is intended for another assembly than C#'s: Assembly **language**. For the kind of assemly you talk about, please use the *.net-assembly* tag

Comment: @tofro thanks for comment, I edited tags.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for this comment, I thought I can compile code dynamically at runtime in memory and users use result of this, but I still don't know how long compiled code is alive? Can I use this method at runtime?